# File permissions by default different when created by different user

Tags: linux, permissions, users

beginner here

I used root privileges to create a new user in Red Hat Enterprise Linux called `john` and a group called `myfriends`. I then added `john` to that group. I also created a folder `/home/myfriends` and made `myfriends` the owner of that folder, and added full group permissions to the folder. Then I changed to the user `john` and created a file in said folder with `touch myfile`. When I do `ls -l` in the folder I get that the file permissions are `-rw-r--r--`, when it should be `-rw-rw-r--` by default. When I log in with my usual user into my home folder and create a random file, it creates it with `-rw-rw-r--` permissions.  Any idea what's going on?

Comment: the keyword you're looking for is "umask". https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/umask/info

Comment: thanks! I was able to dig into the /etc/bashrc and it turns out the umask is different when the user belongs to no other group than his private group and when the user belongs to another group other than his private group.